# If I resize images using Tensorflow Object Detection API, are the bboxes automatically resized too?

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow's Object Detection API has an option in the `.config` file to add an `keep_aspect_ratio_resizer`. If I resize my training data using this, will the corresponding bounding boxes be resized as well? If they don't match up then the network is seeing incorrect examples.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the boxes will be resized to be compatible with the images as well!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!